# UICollectionViewCell size zero in storyboard

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, xcode8

[image]
[image]

[image]

I dragged the UICollectionView in the storyboard , The UICollectionViewCell size then changed to 0,0,0,0.

The height of the UICollectionView is 0,64,375,60.

The height of CollectionView cell is , with deducting top spacing(5) and bottom spacing(5). i.e Size is (55,55)

[image]

The scroll direction is horizontal.

Don't know why I don't see the cell.

My Further findings , I found if the CollectionView is outside the View(green border), then it shows up fine. But as soon as I move inside that view the UICollectionViewCell disappears.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the issue. The problem was Adjust Scroll View Insets of that viewController was checked.

Unchecking that option, solved my issue.

[image]